# How do I prepare time-series data to predict the change in a response variable, rather than the value of the response variable itself?

Tags: machine-learning, pandas, forecasting

I am forecasting solar irradiance using different time series models. Rather than predict the irradiance from $t=0 \text{ min}$ to $t=120 \text{ min}$, I would like to predict the change in irradiance relative to $t=0$ such that for each prediction, the prediction would be $\text{Relative Irradiance}_{t+30} = \text{Irradiance}_{t+30} - \text{Irradiance}_{t}$. Right now, I have all my data in a pandas dataframe.

TLDR: How can I format data for ML prediction of a new relative response variable: the change in the variable from time of prediction.

Answer (score 2):

You can just add a "Relative Irradiance" column and predict it instead of "Irradiance"

Translated in python, something like this should do the job

```
df["Relative_Irradiance"] = df["Irradiance"].values - df["Irradiance"].values[0]
```